# emacs console mode Org-mode strike-through is not displayed as expected

Tags: emacs, terminal, console, org-mode, strikethrough

I'm using org-mode. Using '+' around a text, it displays correctly in the GUI as strike-through text (example: <strike>+striked-through+</strike>).

But this doesn't work in the emacs console mode, the text is not displayed striked-through: there are no difference with the default face.

My term know how to display strike-through as it properly displays striked-through text with this test:

```
echo -e "\e[9mtest\e[0m"
```

So this seems to be emacs not using the SGR code to render the text as strike-through.

Do you know any way to tell emacs to use strike-through in console ? Or is it on my end that something is not set ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (Linux) virtual console does not implement strike-through.  A few terminal emulators do this, but generally those are not referred to as "console".  At most, emacs could show some *other* type of highlighting such as color.

The reference for the strike-through escape sequence is ECMA-48.  However, keep in mind the fact that it was created by a committee and did not represent *existing* practice.  Rather, it is a framework for both existing and *proposed* implementations.  Many of the features described in it have not (30 years later) been implemented. You will not find strike-through as a standard terminfo (or termcap) capability, simply because few (if any) terminals implemented the feature.  Read [`terminfo(5)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html): there is no capability defined for this purpose.

If you read the source code for emacs, it's easy to see that it does not support strike-through.  emacs' driver for terminals `term.c` uses termcap and lists the supported video attributes in a [bitmask](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/term.c#n109):

```
enum no_color_bit
{
  NC_STANDOUT    = 1 << 0,
  NC_UNDERLINE   = 1 << 1,
  NC_REVERSE     = 1 << 2,
  NC_ITALIC  = 1 << 3,
  NC_DIM     = 1 << 4,
  NC_BOLD    = 1 << 5,
  NC_INVIS   = 1 << 6,
  NC_PROTECT     = 1 << 7
};
```

It also retrieves many string capabilities using `tgetstr` ([see code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/term.c#n4048)).  There is no strike-through there.  While emacs [hardcodes some of the color](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/term.c#n2102) escapes (to work around limitations of termcap), the driver contains nothing that would do strike-through.

Further reading:

- [console_codes - Linux console escape and control sequences](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)
- [Why doesn't xterm support italics?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#why_no_italics) ([since 2014](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_305), xterm)
- [[vte/vte-next] emulation: Support italic text](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-October/msg02191.html) (since 2012, vte)

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer with sources.

Comment: This excellent answer inspired me to [patch](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=e0e147e10389e407531ca81d0063a11a5716d765) Emacs 28 to support rendering faces with the strike-through attribute on TTY frames. It's worth noting, since this was written we now have the `smxx` terminfo/termcap attributes. Thank you Mr. Dickey for all your excellent writing and work on xterm/terminfo/termcap!